# Stuck in an infinite loop when trying to loop back to the beginning. Java

Tags: java, swing, loops, infinite-loop, joptionpane

I am trying to get the code to loop if the user input an invalid size. It is stuck in an infinite loop though. I tried bringing "while" to the bottom and adding "do" to start the loop but I am either getting the same results or the code stops without looping back to the beginning.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class BarkingLotJOP5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String size;
        Double sm = 8.00, md = 12.00, lg = 17.00, total, tax = .09;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to BarkingLot.com.");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is $5 for small, $10 for medium, and $15 for large.");

        size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the dog's size.");

        while
            (!size.equals("small") || size.equals("medium")|| size.equals("large"))
                {
        if
            (size.equalsIgnoreCase("small"))
               {
                 total = (sm*tax)+sm;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"For a small dog, your total is "+ df.format(total)+
                                                                      "\nThank you, have a great day!");
               }
        else
        if
            (size.equalsIgnoreCase("medium"))
               {
                 total = (md*tax)+md;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"For a medium dog, your total is "+ df.format(total)+
                                                                               "\nThank you, have a great day!");
               }
        else
        if
            (size.equalsIgnoreCase("Large"))
                           {
                             total = (lg*tax)+lg;
                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"For a large dog, your total is "+ df.format(total)+
                                                            "\nThank you, have a great day!");
                    }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check the size in the loop until it is one of the recommended sizes.  Once you have one of the allowed sizes, do the other messaging.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(!(size.equals("small") || size.equals("medium")|| size.equals("large")))
```

(Notice the braces). Basically your code checked like:

Keep looping if:

Size is not equal to: `small`

or

Size is *equal* to: `medium`

or

Size is *equal* to: `large`

**But you want:**

Keep looping if:

Size is **not** equal to (small or medium or large)

**EDIT:**

In the else condition instead of:

```
else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
```

you can use:

```
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error, try again");
    size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the dog's size.");
}
```

This will make the input box appear again and set the value of size again to newer value.

Comment: this still won't stop the infinite loop because the code needs to check the value of size inside the loop.  Currently it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry about that part, almost missed it. Anyway, added code to fix that. Thanks for edit suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**`break` statement will do the trick for you.**
And remove the `!` sign in front of `!size.equals("small")`

```
    while (size.equals("small") || size.equals("medium") || size.equals("large")) {
        if (size.equalsIgnoreCase("small")) {
            total = (sm * tax) + sm;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "For a small dog, your total is " + df.format(total)
                    + "\nThank you, have a great day!");
            break;
        } else if (size.equalsIgnoreCase("medium")) {
            total = (md * tax) + md;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "For a medium dog, your total is " + df.format(total)
                    + "\nThank you, have a great day!");
            break;
        } else if (size.equalsIgnoreCase("Large")) {
            total = (lg * tax) + lg;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "For a large dog, your total is " + df.format(total)
                    + "\nThank you, have a great day!");
            break;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
            break;
        }
    }
```

**Update :**
I recommend you to use `switch` instead of `while` in this case. It looks more accurate for me.

```
    switch (size) {

        case "small":
            total = (sm * tax) + sm;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "For a small dog, your total is " + df.format(total)
                    + "\nThank you, have a great day!");
            break;
        case "medium":
            total = (md * tax) + md;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "For a medium dog, your total is " + df.format(total)
                    + "\nThank you, have a great day!");
            break;
        case "large":
            total = (lg * tax) + lg;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "For a large dog, your total is " + df.format(total)
                    + "\nThank you, have a great day!");
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
            break;

    }
```

Comment: you don't need the while loop for this part of the code

Comment: Yes. switch is enough.. :)

Comment: But wont the `switch` code stop once `default` case executes? What if he wants to iterate again and again till user enters correct value (and it appears like thats what he is trying to do)?

Answer (score 0):

Prompt in the loop.

> `do {    size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the dog's size.");`

blah blah blah

```
}
while (!(size.equals("small") || size.equals("medium") || size.equals("large")))
```

Add parentheses to while.

Rest is fine